# Splitting a mixed number string from a dataframe column and converting it to a float

Tags: python, pandas, split, fractions

I have a dataframe with a column of strings that are a mix of whole numbers and mixed fractions. I would like to convert column 'y' to floats.

```
x            y         z
0            4      Info
1        8 1/2      Info
2          3/4      Info
3           10      Info
4            4      Info
5        6 1/4      Info
```

The logic I am considering is to split column 'y' by ' ' and '/' to create three separate columns that would look like this.

```
x         base        b        c         z
0            4        0        0      Info
1            8        1        2      Info
2            0        3        4      Info
3           10        0        0      Info
4            4        0        0      Info
5            6        1        4      Info
```

From here I could

```
def convertReplace(df):
    convert = lambda x: float(x)
    df['base'].apply(convert)
    df['b'].apply(convert)
    df['c'].apply(convert)
    decimal = lambda x,y: x/y        
    try:
        df['d'] = decimal(df['b'],df['c'])
        df['y'] = df['base'] + df['d']
    except:
        df['y'] = df['base']
    return df
```

This might work but I can't get the column to split using the method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/pandas-dataframe-how-do-i-split-a-column-into-two).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.y.str.split(' ',1).str.split('/',1).tolist(),columns = ['base','b','c'])
```

The error says it expects 3 arguments each time when it may be 1, 2, or 3. Even [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317342/pandas-dataframe-split-column-into-multiple-columns-right-align-inconsistent-c) doesn't use multiple separators.

The actual dataframe has over 400k rows. Efficiency would be great but I'm more interested in just getting it done. Is this logic correct or is there a more concise way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module. Here's a one-liner:

```
import fractions
df['y_float'] = df['y'].apply(lambda frac: float(sum([fractions.Fraction(x) for x in frac.split()])))
```

This gives:

```
       y     z  y_float
0      4  Info     4.00
1  8 1/2  Info     8.50
2    3/4  Info     0.75
3     10  Info    10.00
4      4  Info     4.00
5  6 1/4  Info     6.25
```

**[EDIT] Corrected version accounting for negative fractions, as well as invalid text:**

I realized the above approach would not work for negative fractions, so here is that taken in to account. As it turns out, a one-liner for this would be very tricky!

```
def get_sign(num_str):
    """
    Verify the sign of the fraction
    """
    return 1-2*num_str.startswith('-')

def is_valid_fraction(text_str):
    """
    Check if the string provided is a valid fraction.
    Here I just used a quick example to check for something of the form of the fraction you have. For something more robust based on what your data can potentially contain, a regex approach would be better.
    """
    return text_str.replace(' ', '').replace('-', '').replace('/', '').isdigit()

def convert_to_float(text_str):
    """
    Convert an incoming string to a float if it is a fraction
    """
     if is_valid_fraction(text_str):
         sgn = get_sign(text_str)
         return sgn*float(sum([abs(fractions.Fraction(x)) for x in text_str.split()]))
     else:
         return pd.np.nan # Insert a NaN if it is invalid text
```

So now you will have this:

```
>>> df['y_float'] = df['y'].apply(lambda frac: convert_to_float(frac))
>>> df
              y     z  y_float
0             4  Info     4.00
1         8 1/2  Info     8.50
2           3/4  Info     0.75
3            10  Info    10.00
4             0  Info     0.00
5         6 1/4  Info     6.25
6        -3 2/5  Info    -3.40
7          -4/5  Info    -0.80
8  gibberish100  Info      NaN
```

Comment: I think this might work but my actual data is a little muddy. A few values include text. How could I apply this but skip the invalid literals the fractions module runs into? Is there an if-else check for format check? Do you use the 'loc' command in that case?

Comment: Updated the solution to address negative fractions and muddy text

Comment: Great! This really helped. Thank you @vk1011!