# Create Multiple New Columns Based on Pipe-Delimited Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a pipe delimited column with an arbitrary number of elements, called Parts. The number of elements in these pipe-strings varies from 0 to over 10. The number of unique elements contained in all pipe-strings is not much smaller than the number of rows (which makes it impossible for me to manually specify all of them while creating new columns).

For each row, I want to create a new column that acts as an indicator variable for each element of the pipe delimited list. For instance, if the row

...`'Parts'`...

...`'12|34|56'`

should be transformed to

...`'Part_12'   'Part_34'   'Part_56'`...

...`1            1           1`...

Because they are a lot of unique parts, these columns are obviously going to be sparse - mostly zeros since each row only contains a small fraction of unique parts.

I haven't found any approach that doesn't require manually specifying the columns (for instance, [Pandas Dataframe: split column into multiple columns, right-align inconsistent cell entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317342/pandas-dataframe-split-column-into-multiple-columns-right-align-inconsistent-c)).
I've also looked at pandas' melt, but I don't think that's the appropriate tool.

The way I know how to solve it would be to pipe the raw CSV to another python script and deal with it on a char-by-char basis, but I need to work within my existing script since I will be processing hundreds of CSVs in this manner.

Here's a better illustration of the data

`ID     YEAR     AMT     PARTZ`

`1202   2007     99.34`

`9321   1988     1012.99  2031|8942`

`2342   2012     381.22   1939|8321|Amx3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_dummies` and `add_prefix`:

```
df.Parts.str.get_dummies().add_prefix('Part_')
```

Output:

```
   Part_12  Part_34  Part_56
0        1        1        1
```

## Edit for comment and counting duplicates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Parts':['12|34|56|12']}, index=[0])
pd.get_dummies(df.Parts.str.split('|',expand=True).stack()).sum(level=0).add_prefix('Part_')
```

Output:

```
   Part_12  Part_34  Part_56
0        2        1        1
```

Comment: this is really elegant. However, it seems to not count duplicates (eg 12|12|34)

Comment: @MikePalmice `pd.get_dummies(df.Parts.str.split('|',expand=True).stack()).sum(level=0).add_prefix('Part_')`

Comment: the two solutions produce dataframes with different dimensions - specifically the second one has 25% as many rows. the indices are 0,3,6,7,9 etc

Comment: Would you mind starting a new question with more roboust data for testing?

Comment: No problem, here's the link-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014555/make-new-pandas-columns-based-on-pipe-delimited-column-with-possible-repeats.  I noticed that the excluded indices have empty values for `Parts`. so the only 'problem' with your revised solution is that it produces NaN instead of 0. However it should be easy to replace NaN with 0 in all columns that begin with 'Part_'. (it was my mistake to examine the result in Excel instead of from the shell!)