# Split a pandas dataframe column into multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the form-

```
Id   Nums

1    0,1,0,0
2    0,0,0,1
```

I wish to split the column `Nums` in the form a feature vector for any Id --

```
Id   Num1   Num2   Num3   Num4

1    0       1       0     0
2    0       0       0     1
```

How can something of this sort can be done?

Comment: A simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Split%20a%20pandas%20dataframe%20column%20into%20multiple%20columns&cad=h) of your title would have yielded [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317342/pandas-dataframe-split-column-into-multiple-columns-right-align-inconsistent-c) [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns/14745484) pages that show how to do this.

Comment: Is the `Nums` columns character or list?

Comment: @pault Entries (0,1,0,0) are seperated via comma & are not in the form of a list.

Comment: @pault do you want me reopen ?

Comment: @RahulDev ok so call str.split() first: like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745022/how-to-split-a-column-into-two-columns/14745484)

Comment: @Wen it's definitely a dupe, maybe I just picked the wrong dupe.

Comment: @pault yep, I will modify the dup link