# Apply the same function on each record of a column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, preprocessor

I have a dataset with a date-time column with a specific format. I need to create new features out of this column that means I need to add new columns to the dataframe by extracting information from the above-mentioned date-time column. My sample input dataframe column is like below.

```
id    datetime         feature2
1    12/3/2020 0:56       1
2    11/25/2020 13:26     0
```

The expected output is:

```
id    date      hour    mints    feature2
1    12/3/2020   0       56         1
2    11/25/2020  13      26         0
```

Pandas apply() method may not work for this as new columns are added. What is the best way to do this?

Is there any way which I can apply a single function on each record of the column to do this by applying on the whole column?

Comment: change the delimiter in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317342/pandas-dataframe-split-column-into-multiple-columns-right-align-inconsistent-c , and join again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### pandas series `.dt` accessor

- Your datetime data is coming from a pandas column (series), so use the [.dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2],
                   'datetime': ['12/3/2020 0:56', '11/25/2020 13:26'],
                   'feature2': [1, 0]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

 id            datetime  feature2
  1 2020-12-03 00:56:00         1
  2 2020-11-25 13:26:00         0

# create columns
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.hour
df['min'] = df['datetime'].dt.minute
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date

# final
 id            datetime  feature2  hour  min        date
  1 2020-12-03 00:56:00         1     0   56  2020-12-03
  2 2020-11-25 13:26:00         0    13   26  2020-11-25
```

Answer (score 1):

IICU

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index(df.date, inplace=True)
df['hour']=df.index.hour
df['mints']=df.index.minute
```